# How to make Master VC appear on the right of a UISplitViewController?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to code an application that has a Master-Detail layout.

But I want the Master VC to appear on the right using UISplitViewController.

Is there any way to make the Master VC appear from the right ?

Comment: Please learn to phrase your questions better :D I almost downvoted but preferred to edit your question !

Comment: ok ... is there any answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SWRevealViewController` provides feature. 
The easiest way to install it is by copying the following to your project:

SWRevealViewController.h
SWRevealViewController.m
On your project:

Initialize an instance of a SWRevealViewController passing in a "rear" and a "front" view controllers.
Optionaly add a "right" view controller or pass nil as the "rear" view controller.
Use the SWRevealViewController instance in your code as you would use any view controller.
Deploy as the application window rootViewController, or as a child of other containment controllers.
Get the panGestureRecognized and tapGestureRecognizer provided by the SWRevealViewController. You can leave them as they are for the default behavior or you can add them to a suitable view on your "front" view controller. For example add the panGestureRecognizer to a navigationBar on the viewDidLoad method of your front controller.
At any time, you can reveal, conceal the "rear" or "right" views or replace any of the view controllers, programmatically or based on user actions, with or without animations enabled

Check below link :

https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController

Comment: I  want ask you another question in the   SWRevealViewController  how can I make the master above the detail ?

Comment: You have to set front,rear,right view controller as per your requirement. and you can set frame of them as per requirement.